# What does: "char *argv[]" mean?

Tags: arrays, c, string, pointers, char

I have this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i;

    for (i=0; i < argc;i++) {
        printf("argv[%d] = %s\n", i, argv[i]);
    }


}
```

I am wondering about the argument `char *argv[]`. My first thought was that this was an **array of character pointers**? But then it should compile if we write: `(char *argv)[]`? But then I get the error meassage

```
testargs.c:3:20: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '(' token
    3 | int main(int argc, (char *argv)[]) {
```

However it will compile and run correctly if I have `char *(argv[])`. But what is this actually in terms of pointers and arrays? Is it a character pointer to an array, or what is it?

Comment: Your first thought is correct. Your parenthesis interpretation is not. argv is what is being declared, so start with that and work out to the right  when possible, to the left when forced to. `char *(argv[])`: argv is array of pointers to char. `(char *argv)[]` argv is pointer to char array of _omitted_ . I'm like the compiler, I don't get that.

Comment: Though since it is a function declarationto be somewhat pedantic and more complete, `type name[]` is implicitly transformed to `type *name` . So char *(argv[]) => `char *(*argv)` and `(char *argv)[]` => `* (char *argv)`

Comment: @Isaiah yes it does

Answer (score 0):

This represents an array of pointers to `char`, in other words, strings. The way you recognize this is that the array syntax `[]` is demoted to a pointer, so this is the same as `**char`, a pointer to pointers of `char`s.

Answer (score -2):

It's an array of pointers to C strings (or char arrays). Where each string in the array is in the first[] and each character is in a second [], and each string of chars is an array of characters typically terminated by a null character or a zero byte.

In main() the argc parameter specifies how many strings there are in the char *arcv[] array.

The operating system when calling into main will specify the number of parameters, the int argc value as well as the command line parameters provided to main() in the char *argv[] parameter.

The first argv parameter is typically the program name itself, and this is followed by any additional parameters specified on the command line.

So for instance if you did:

```
./program.bin parameter1 --option1
```

And the data in it would be dereferenced like this:

```
puts(argv[0]) // would be "./program.bin"
puts(argv[1]) // would be "parameter1"
puts(argv[2]) // would be "--option1"
```

and argc would be 3.

The way i'd think of this is as char **argv, in fact you can replace char *argv[] as char **argv.

And I would think of this in the layout `char *(argv[stringnum])` or `char (argv[stringnum])[letternum]` or just `char argv[stringnum][letternum]`

Now, the reason:

```
(char *argv)[]
```

doesn't work is, is because your declaration of the variable argv is embedded within some code to dereference it and the compiler is confused about whether it's a declaration or a function. In the error message it thinks it should be a declaration, but it doesn't understand the format. Instead use `char *argv[]` or `char **argv`